# How do I create curved zones in KiCad?

Tags: kicad

I'm trying to create an accurate, curved copper fill to reduce impedance on a GaN circuit. I.e I'm trying to create a file such as this example from a particular manufacturer:

[image]

However, I'm trying to create a zone in this area around via's I've placed I'm seeing something much less tidy:

[image]

How do I tidy these areas up such that they're smooth and as straight as possible?

Comment: Well, if you make the via diameter exactly the same as the trace diameter, that ought to help matters.

Comment: Alex Turner - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing) copied / adapted material, please [edit] the question & add the **name** and **link** of the PDF / video / webpage etc. which was the source of that copied image. (Or, if you copied it from a book or other non-web source, please add a full citation - see the rule for details.) Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. Thanks.

Comment: Improvements like these make little to no difference in the signals, unless you have a strict gap requirement

Comment: You can also see here if it helps: https://forum.kicad.info/t/how-can-i-add-curved-filled-zone/38628

Answer (score 0):

You could start with what you have, then define a rectangular keep-out zone (define the check-boxes to exclude copper fills in that one plane, but not traces or vias), and edit the keep-out zone corner radius to whatever suits your needs.

As noted in comment, also increase your trace width or reduce via diameter. This is simpler - but if you're using different clearances in this structure for some reason, defining a keep-out zone might make for more intuitive editing down the road. You decide.

Comment: Or reduce the via diameter.

Comment: @Hearth - yep. thanks